# Border color become the same color as my text (css/html)

Tags: html, css

I have a problem while creating a table, I want to change the text color depending on certain conditions, but the cell border becomesthe same color as my text for some reasons.

[image]

Here is the code

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-baqh {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-edkd {
  color: #9a0000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-kxdw {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #036400;
  color: #ecf4ff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-24w0 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-9ewa {
  color: #fe0000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-yw4l {
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-cd3k {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #036400;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-zlvv {
  color: #3531ff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-24w0" colspan="6">Nomenclature de Nomenclature, OF054453, OF054581, OF054600, OF054395, OF054063,</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Action</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Poste</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Pièce</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Description</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Quantité initiale ? Nouvelle quantité</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Code lien procédure</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-9ewa">Retirer</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">4000</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">TJA1050TD-T</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">CI COM H-SPEED CAN TX SO8 SMT</td>
    <td class="tg-edkd">1 ? 0</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">PM120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="6">Commentaire Ligne : </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="6">Remarques : </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use secund attribute:

```html
<style>
 
 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
 }

 .tg {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
 }
 .red {
  color: red;
 }
 .green {
  color: green;
 }
 
</style>
 
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="tg">Text 1</td>
  <td class="tg red">Text 2</td>
  <td class="tg green">Text 3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify a border color together with your border width and style on `.tg td` like in this edited snippet:

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg .tg-baqh {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-edkd {
  color: #9a0000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-kxdw {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #036400;
  color: #ecf4ff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-24w0 {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 22px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-9ewa {
  color: #fe0000;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-yw4l {
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-cd3k {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #036400;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-zlvv {
  color: #3531ff;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-24w0" colspan="6">Nomenclature de Nomenclature, OF054453, OF054581, OF054600, OF054395, OF054063,</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Action</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Poste</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Pièce</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Description</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Quantité initiale ? Nouvelle quantité</td>
    <td class="tg-kxdw">Code lien procédure</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-9ewa">Retirer</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">4000</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">TJA1050TD-T</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">CI COM H-SPEED CAN TX SO8 SMT</td>
    <td class="tg-edkd">1 ? 0</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh">PM120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="6">Commentaire Ligne : </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l" colspan="6">Remarques : </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The **color** CSS property sets the foreground color value of an element's text content and text decorations. It also sets the currentcolor value, which may be used as an indirect value on other properties, and is the default for other color properties, such as **border-color**. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color)

To solve this problem just add [border-color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-color.asp) property to .tg td as below:

```css
.tg td {
  border-color:black;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: normal;
}
```